# Set SQLite data to JsonObject class without using Stringbuilder

Tags: java, json, sqlite, android, gson

Am retrieving information from my SQLite database to display on CardView

My SQLite database structure is [SQLite DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qocq4.png)

My class is

```
 public class ServiceRequest{
    public String reqid;
    public String name;
    public String branch;
    public Date date;
    public Date time;
    public String services;
    //Getter and setter
    .............
    .............
   }
```

I can convert this to JSON format  using

```
    List<ServiceRequest> reqs = getAllReqs();
    List<ServiceRequest> jobservList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (ServiceRequest access : reqs) {
        ServiceRequest ob = new ServiceRequest();

        ob.setId(access.getId());
        ob.setBranch(access.getBranch());
        ob.setName(access.getName());
        ob.setDate(access.getDate());
        ob.setTime(access.getTime());
        ob.setServices(access.getServices());
        jobservList.add(ob);
    }

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    String json2 = gson.toJson(jobservList);
    return json2;
```

but  my desired JSONObject format is

```
{  
 "100": {

        "name": "Rahul Suresh",
        "branch": "Koramangala",
        "phNumber":"123456",
        "date": "2016-08-06",
        "time": "16:00",
        "reqServices": "Loans"
       },
 "200": {
         "name": "Sidh",
         "branch": "Jayanagar",
         "phNumber":"182694",
         "date": "2016-08-12",
         "time": "11:00",
         "reqServices": "OpenAcc,SafeDeposit"
        }
  }
```

so that I will get one whole JSON object with a single call

```
JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get(Integer.toString(id));
```

100,200 are 'reqid' s

It's possible to achieve this using string builder. But is there any other ways to implement this like using an object mapper along with a class or something..?

Comment: Your class structure is not correct if you want to use an object mapper like Gson or Jackson. The ID would have to be in the inner object, not the key

Comment: @cricket_007 Ya am aware of that...Since I want JSON on the given format am searching a way other than making a string builder.

Comment: It is possible with a Hashmap of integer to your class, then have Gson convert that

Comment: @cricket_007 Can you gimme a small sketch how that class will be?!!

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to form the JSON you have shown, you could "pull out" the ID into a HashMap key, then set the value to be your object.

I can't remember how Gson handles the conversion of the object values in the map, but this is the general idea

```
List<ServiceRequest> reqs = getAllReqs();

HashMap<Integer, ServiceRequest> map = new HashMap<Integer, ServiceRequest>();
for (ServiceRequest access : reqs) {
    map.put(access.getId(), access);
}

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String json2 = gson.toJson(map); // TODO: Not sure if this will work
return json2;
```